# Getting a type error when trying to create custom color mappings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create two-color mappings but keep getting this error:

TypeError: to_rgb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'

I've tried searching this up but had trouble so I came here. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import pickle    
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
color_map = plt.cm.winter
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon
import math
from PIL import Image
# Needed for custom colour mapping
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap,LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

c = mcolors.ColorConverter().to_rgb()
positive_cm = ListedColormap([c('#e1e5e5'),c('#d63b36')])
negative_cm = ListedColormap([c('#e1e5e5'),c('#28aee4')])
```

Comment: Maybe just use `positive_cm = ListedColormap(['#e1e5e5','#d63b36'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation for `matplotlib`:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgb.html

you need to pass the color as an argument to the `to_rgb` function.  If your intent is to assign that function to `c`, then all you need to do is remove the parens so that you're not attempting to actually call it (with no arguments):

```
c = mcolors.ColorConverter().to_rgb
```

I might suggest letting it keep a slightly more meaningful name (and maybe cleaning up some of those imports):

```
from matplotlib import colors

ListedColorMap = colors.ListedColorMap
to_rgb = colors.ColorConverter().to_rgb

positive_cm = ListedColormap([to_rgb('#e1e5e5'), to_rgb('#d63b36')])
negative_cm = ListedColormap([to_rgb('#e1e5e5'), to_rgb('#28aee4')])
```